# How to add a send email action link in views using the same VBO send email action

Tags: emails, views

Views Bulk Operations (VBO) has a send email action that sends you to an email form. How can I add a views field to a list of users that creates a link to the same action form that VBO uses to send email, but for just that user row and then pre-populate the recipient field? I believe VBO uses the system_send_email_action_form.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this with VBO you'll need modify the `system_send_email_action_form` form (to default its recipient) and add some custom JS (to create click events that automatically submit the VBO form).

An easier alternative here is to use the [Views Send](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_send) module which does nearly the same thing with a slight UI difference; there's a **Send Email** button at the bottom of the view as opposed to a send email link for each row.